# Npm update in windows

Tags: node.js, npm

While I was updating npm under this command npm-windows-upgrade 
it is showing this

[image]

what should I do next?

Comment: A copy paste from the command line would be better than an image.

Comment: Did you execute the command under administrative privilege?

Answer (score 0):

Run the Command it says to run.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing your approach to updating your NPM.

Use cURL in [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) to install your NPM instead of using npm-windows-upgrade

`curl -L "https://npmjs.com/install.sh" | sh`